# How do I assign a value from one cell to another?

Tags: excel

I wasn't really sure how to word the question but here is the problem I'm facing:

---

I have a list of MLB teams in column A and their batting averages in column B. In another worksheet I have a schedule listing the home and away teams for the entire season. I want to see the batting average next to the team name on the schedule without having to manually type it in for every game. Is there a way to tell Excel to use the number next to the team name from the first sheet and enter it next to the team name on the second sheet?

For example on the first worksheet I have SEA in column A and .237 in column B. Every time SEA shows up on the second worksheet I want .237 to be in the column next to it.

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP.

Comment: I second that. `VLOOKUP` is there for a reason, but it is old school. Now there is `XLOOKUP` to replace it. *look it up*.

Comment: I used VLOOKUP and it worked great, thank you!